# Drag and copy with a swap function

Tags: javascript

I have created a user interface that has a working drag and copy in javascript. My problem is the div getting copied has a hidden div that i need to swap once they reach the dropzone. Upon dragging the visible div gets a new id but the hidden one doesn't and when i swap them it swaps to the hidden div in it's original position. Here is my javascript code:

These work the drag and copy functions.

```
  function allowDrop(ev) {
      /* The default handling is to not allow dropping elements. */
      /* Here we allow it by preventing the default behaviour. */
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      /* Here is specified what should be dragged. */
      /* This data will be dropped at the place where the mouse button is released */
      /* Here, we want to drag the element itself, so we set it's ID. */
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
      /* If you use DOM manipulation functions, their default behaviour it not to
         copy but to alter and move elements. By appending a ".cloneNode(true)",
         you will not move the original element, but create a copy. */
      var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
      nodeCopy.id = "newId"; /* We cannot use the same ID */
      ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    }
    </script>
This function works the divs swap

    <script type="text/javascript">
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2)
{
 d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
 d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
 if( d2.style.display == "none" )
 {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "block";
 }
 else
 {
    d1.style.display = "block";
    d2.style.display = "none";
 }
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to drag the hidden div along with the visible one? Can the hidden div also be assigned a new number so it can be swapped?

Thank you

Comment: please, improve format code

Comment: I hope that is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this little riddle. The divs swap when dragged into the drop zone there's no need to have them swap on a mouse click. Anyway here are the javascript functions that i used, i had to modify the drag and copy from the previous one I posted.

```
<script> 
function allowDrop(ev) { 
ev.preventDefault(); 
} 

function drag(ev) { 
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id); 
} 

function drop(ev) { 
ev.preventDefault(); 
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"); 
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true)); 
} 
</script> 
{{--Works the swap functions--}} 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2) 
{ 
d1 = document.getElementById(div1); 
d2 = document.getElementById(div2); 
if( d2.style.display == "none" ) 
{ 
d1.style.display = "none"; 
d2.style.display = "block"; 
} 
else 
{ 
d1.style.display = "block"; 
d2.style.display = "none"; 
} 
} 
</script>
```

Here is 1 set of components incase it helps someone else:

```
<div id="swapper-two" style="display:none; padding:0px;"> 
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1"> 
<tr> 
<td align="left" bgcolor="40374B" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 60px;"> 
<a href="" style="font-family:Helvetica Neue"><img src="" valign="top" alt="" draggable="false" color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"</a> 
<td style="color:#ffffff; padding:0px 60px 5px 0px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;" bgcolor="40374B" align="right" valign="bottom"> 
<p><a href="" span style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" >Login&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">My Account</a></p> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</div> 
<div class="img" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag9"> 
<div id="swapper-one" style="display:block; padding:0px;" > 
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1"> 
<tr> 
<td align="center"> 
<img src="" draggable="false" alt="" width="610" height="270" id="img-one" /> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</div> 
</div>
```